# Spring MVC @ResponseBody giving ERROR HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to create a simple restful web service code with spring. 
Here is the complete code I have created so far:

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>TemporaryTry01</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.arman"/>
</beans>
```

**Student.java**:

```
package com.arman.dta;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
public class Student {
    @JsonProperty("student_name")
    private String studentName;
    private long mobileNo;

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public long getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }
    public void setMobileNo(long mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.arman.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import com.arman.dta.Student;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/students", method=RequestMethod.GET) // already Tried to add produces attribute explicitly with MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE but that too is not working
    public ArrayList<Student> getStudentList(){
        Student st = new Student();
        st.setStudentName("Arman");
        st.setMobileNo(903434555L);

        Student st1 = new Student();
        st1.setStudentName("Avasthi");
        st1.setMobileNo(779232245L);

        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(st);
        studentList.add(st1);
        return studentList;
    }
}
```

I have added all the spring jars (version-4.2.2), commons-logging jar and also 3 Jackson jars namely:
jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar
jackson-core-2.8.1.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar

I am not getting any compile time issue using Eclipse Oxygen IDE. But when I run the project (**on Tomcat 8 on port number 7070**) and try to access:

```
http://localhost:7070/TemporaryTry01/students
```

I get the following Error page

[image]

And in stack trace it shows:

> Dec 10, 2017 8:51:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver logException
>   WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation